# Requiring a module inside a required module

Tags: lua, coronasdk, require

I am programming a game in Lua based Corona that requires that I require a module inside of another module. I am getting a looping error.  The reason I am doing it this way is because I need to use a function that I have defined in main.lua in a module that itself is required in main.lua.  To solve that problem, I decided I would hold my game state in a separate module called gameState.lua.  But then, I get the circular requirement error.  Is there any way to get around this in Corona SDK?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I need to use a function that I have defined in main.lua in a module that itself is required in main.lua.

Move that function out to a third module and require it in the other two.